# What is JVT in Java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I recently heard JVT and found [this](http://www.geekinterview.com/question_details/56625) . As it states,

> JVT is used for synchronous process. It uses Java Objects for communications. Java Objects are sent across the networks.

I googled on it, but couldn't find any useful sources. Any one has a good explanation with how JVT goes in Java and when, how, where... JVT is useful?

I also found [from here](http://java-vision-toolkit.soft112.com/)

> The Java Vision Toolkit (JVT) is a Java Advanced Imaging GUI/library for machine vision and image processing applications. It provides a framework for machine vision and image processing algorithms for 2D and 3D images.

Comment: It looks like there are two completely unrelated JVT projects... one is about distributed systems and one is about computer imaging. Which one are you asking about?

Answer (score 4):

**first of all, what is JMS?** :
Java Message Service (JMS) is an application program interface (API) from Sun Microsystems that supports the formal communication known as messaging between computers in a network. here message can be of any type (Integer, Float, string) and of any size. Like in Socket programming, we use some API to send messages across network.

now, **how JVT is related to JMS?** :
JVT (Java Value Type) is manages entities. it is like an Object. as i specified above, JMS is used to send messages across network and this message can be of any type. This message can also be mixture of types (int + String). to clarify this look at example below:

```
class CustomerJVT{
     int CustomerId
     String CustomerName
}
```

Here CustomerJVT is JVT which we can send on network using JMS library easily instead of sending CustomerId and CustomerName separately. isn't it good?

**referances:**
http://www2.sys-con.com/itsg/virtualcd/java/archives/0805/horton/index.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncdq.html

I hope it clarifies your issue. If you need any further clarification than let me know.

Thanks,

Comment: Thank you very much...  1. clarifying the types JVT  in comments   2. explaining as Java Value Type. I was looking for Java Value Type.

Comment: so... JVT is something like a container to carry the data as a serialized object ? right ?  But, JMS's based frameworks (For instance ActiveMq) provides trasnfering objects too. So, JVT is required more over ?

Comment: JVT is just a concept. JMS is providing the transfering objects (which is also conceptually JVT).